# Making responsive website with a background and form

Tags: html, css

I want to make a website that has a background in the center and it is height is the whole site, and at the end of the background I want to pace a form, so where I zoom in our out the site still responsive and the form changes size as the background and still  at the same position

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:100,200,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700,400,300);
html, body {
  height:4400px;
  width: 100%;
}

*
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body
{
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(images/myimage.jpg);
  background-size: auto 100%;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
}


#login-form
{
  margin-top: 3700px;
  position: relative;

}
table
{
  padding:10px;
  background: transparent  ;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
table tr,td
{
  padding:2px;
  //border:solid #e1e1e1 1px;
}
table tr td input[type=text]
{
  width:97%;
  height:45px;
  border:solid #e1e1e1 1px;
  border-radius:3px;
  padding-left:10px;
  font-family:'Exo', sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  background: transparent  ;

  transition-duration:0.5s;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
textarea {
  width: 97%;
  height: 135px;
  resize: none;
  border:solid #e1e1e1 1px;
  border-radius:3px;
  padding-left:10px;
  font-family:'Exo', sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  background: transparent  ;
  color: #909


    transition-duration:0.5s;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
table tr td input[type=checkbox]
{
  width:5%;
  height:15px;

}

table tr td input[type=submit]
{
  width:100%;
  height:45px;
  border:solid #e1e1e1 1px;
  border-radius:3px;
  padding-left:10px;
  font-family:'Exo', sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  background: #128195  ;
  color: #e63b5f;

  transition-duration:0.5s;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

table tr td button
{
  width:100%;
  height:45px;
  border:0px;
  background:rgba(12,45,78,11);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #595959 , #515151);
  border-radius:3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(1,0,0,0.2);
  color:#f9f9f9;
  font-family:'Exo', sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bolder;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
table tr td button:active
{
  position:relative;
  top:1px;
}
table tr td a
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#00a2d1;
  font-family:'Exo', sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
}
label
{
  height: auto;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#00a2d1;
  font-family:'Exo', sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thesite">
  <center>
    <div id="login-form">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td><input class='inputs' type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="first_name"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input class='inputs' type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email" name="email"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><textarea  name="message" placeholder="Enter your Order"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="copy" value="value1">Send me copy from the order</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem when zooming in/out and with of the form comes from your HTML-Code. You set the `width`-attribute in the `table`-element. It is obsolete to set the `width` of elements via HTML-attribute, you should use CSS instead. Also the other attributes like `align` and `border` should be removed.

Simply change:

```
<table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
```

to:

```
<table>
```

Such properties should be set with CSS only. Removing those fixed the zoom-issue for me (Chrome).

Also, I think what you are doing with the `background-image` is not the right approach. You should rather try to insert a new `div` containing the image, than to use the `background-image` of the `body`. Also when inserting a `div`, you don't need to add `margin-top` to the form anymore.